# How do I add a group to the Dynamics CRM NavBar?

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm-2011

I have been editting the sitemap xml for my current Dynamics CRM instance, but I would like to, if possible, find a way to *add* a group without modifying or deleting all of the existing groups that are already part of the SiteMap area.

Is this possible?  Will I need to always include the XML for *all* of the existing groups if I want to add a new one?

Comment: I have a feeling that if you add a new area, this will be OK. Not sure about groups, but fairly sure I have imported ISV solutions that ended up adding a group (eg under Settings) so it sounds feasible. Are you trying to do this for a solution to import into unknown environments, or just for your convenience? If it is your own system, stop hacking the xml and use sitemapeditor.codeplex.com to hugely increase your speed and sanity.

Comment: Unfortunately it's for solutions that will be imported into unknown environments, so I'm stuck with xml-hacking for a bit.  I've tried simply adding a single area, but without the existing areas also added it seems to -only- add the new area, clearing the rest out